# Securely changing Oracle DB passwords from JDBC

Tags: oracle, security, jdbc

I'm exploring some options for changing Oracle user passwords via a Java application utilizing the JDBC.  To preface my question with a little background, I'm using Oracle 11gR2 as my RDBMS platform and do not have a license for the Advanced Security Option.

What I'd like to do is change several user account passwords based on GUI input.  The problem I currently have is that I'm unable to locate specific JDBC functionality to securely change passwords.  I realize that passwords are always securely transmitted during login, but not necessarily encrypted in an ALTER statement (ALTER USER XYZ IDENTIFIED BY "newpassword"), for example.

If I were connected directly to the RDBMS instance via SQL*Plus, I could use the PASSWORD command, but I do not believe this is an option from my Java application.

Does anyone have an idea how to approach/solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this [Does Oracle OCI function OCIPasswordChange encrypt transmitted password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899426/does-oracle-oci-function-ocipasswordchange-encrypt-transmitted-password) or this http://blog.flimatech.com/2011/12/29/a-standalone-utility-to-change-oracle-password/ helps. I can't guarantee that in the latter example the new password is encrypted, but there is a good chance that it is, since it is sent to the server as a part of the initial connection.